# Customized ListView:Multiple choice List Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using a customized list view, as shown below:

list_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:background="#ffffff" 
android:textColor="#000000">
```

Activity file extending ListActivity:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));       
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

We use this code for multiple list item selection:

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            hometown));
```

But I have changed the 2nd argument of ArrayAdapter to a customized TextView, hence i dont understand where to put the option for multiple choice of list items.

Please help

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
 lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

you can use the above line below

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Updated::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#000000">
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    
    android:text="check it out" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

use these xml file instead of yours and replace this adapter in your code

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES,new Int[] {R.id.textview1})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the option you suggested but it is not working. No checkbox appears beside the Items present in the ListView. Please suggest

Comment: i got a class cast exception:Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: simply use setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            COUNTRIES));

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter